# Does percent_rank() analytic function return correct output for rows in partition

Tags: monetdb

Consider the below query which is based on sample VOC dataset provided by MonetDB. I am trying to find the percent_rank() over partition by trip.

```
SELECT number, trip, tonnage, departure_Date, arrival_date,
RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY trip ORDER BY tonnage ) AS RankAggregation,
PERCENT_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY trip ORDER BY tonnage ) as PercentRankGroup
FROM voyages WHERE particulars LIKE '%_recked%';
```

Ideally, the percent_rank() over partition should ideally be calculated as (rank() - 1) / (**rows in partition** - 1). But as per observations from output of above query, this is being calculated as (rank() - 1) / (**total rows**  - 1) which is resulting in incorrect output for partitions [PercentRankGroup column in above query].

Can anyone point to me if the query is incorrect in someway. Is there any alternate way to calculate the same ( we can use directly rank() and count() over).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that I just fixed it. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Can you share bug details and when it will be available(usually it is available in coming releases).

Comment: It should be available on our next bugfix release.